# Draw tikz loop with two sources

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to reproduce something similar to this image in tikz

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} [
    node distance = 5cm, 
    on grid, 
    auto,
    every loop/.style={stealth-}]
 
% State q1    
\node (q1) [state,
    accepting] {$q$};
 
% Arrows
\path [-stealth, thick]
    (q1) edge [loop above]  node {$\overline{\beta_i} | \beta_j$}();
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I have two sources, as in the image above?

Comment: Place the nodes with the betas first and then connect them with three edges or possible a `double`d edge with `1` and `2` and a normal edge with arrow tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to place the node with betas first and then just draw edges.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  arrows={[scale=.75]},
  every edge quotes/.append style={inner sep=+.15em, node font=\footnotesize}]
\node (q1) [state, accepting] {$q$};
\node (bb)[above right=0mm and 1cm of q1] {$\overline{\beta_1} \vert \beta_j$};
\path[thick, in=180, at end]
  (q1) edge[out=45, "1" above left] ([yshift= .75ex]bb.west)
       edge[out=30, "2" below left] ([yshift=-.75ex]bb.west)
  (bb) edge[-Latex, out=0, in=-15] (q1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: If this is needed more often we might pack that up in a nice shortcut/style, maybe.